# asdvantages of using Spec DSL in Minitest?

Tags: minitest

I am using rails default mimitesting framework. Today i see **minitest-rails** gem. minitest-rails is a replacement for the default Rails testing engine that enables Minitest features like the Spec DSL that Rails disables by default. **But i don't really understand the concept of Spec DSL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use of the spec DSL is purely preference. The spec DSL was popularised by RSpec, so if you are familiar with RSpec and enjoy using it you can add a similar spec DSL to minitest.

There are no advantages to using or not using the spec DSL.